# Tag wiki edit proposal bug

Tags: support, tag-wiki, suggested-edits

I've seen this several times already:

[image]

Note the timestamps on the two edits, they were submitted at the same time.  The 2nd part of the edit often looks like a pointless one, as it did in this case.  I probably shouldn't have rejected it.

Comment: I retagged this to "support", if there is a concrete way you would like me to improve the UI please let me know

Comment: Suggested tag edits should have a UI that enables reviewing them _in context_ to each other. Currently, they arrive independently in the queue. I may fix tons of spelling mistakes in the wiki, yet only find one in the excerpt — editors should always fix _everything_ in a post —, but if this is split into two suggestions, the excerpt suggestion may get rejected because it only fixes a single mistake. Example: [critical mistake in excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26840108), [but wiki edit has one reject vote](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26840107).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tag wikis are made of two parts ....

Part one is the excerpt (which shows up in the hover menu) - it is linked to post 1

Part two is the wiki body (which shows up when you view the wiki) - it is linked to a second post.

When people edit tag wikis they trigger edits on 2 posts. In this particular case there was and edit to the excerpt (titled: libsndfile tag wiki excerpt) and and edit to the wiki body.

---

Sometimes people do a good job with an excerpt edit and a bad job with the wiki edit. So it is split to allow us the fidelity to accept or reject a part.

---

All that said, there is certainly a bug in the UI if it is confusing you. How would you clarify this?

Comment: Never noticed "excerpt" on the blue label on the left before.  Well, I know it's there now...