# Should I have gotten the Tag Editor badge?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, tag-wiki, edit-badges

I saw [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94381/160382) which suggests that some fix was applied to the *Tag Editor* badge recently.

However, I did [suggest an edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/988) for the *Newsletter* tag that got accepted on July 21st, should I have gotten the badge for this? Because I didn't ... if I should've gotten it, there's still some problem ...

Comment: [This has been fixed](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/936/tag-editor-badge-bug-detected/937#937) - you'll get the badge now when editing an excerpt first.

Answer (score 3):

You edited the tag wiki *excerpt*, the summary that shows when you mouse over the tag.

I'll have to dig up where it was published, but in order to get the badge, you must edit the main body of a tag wiki.

Edit: This [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78616/tag-wiki-edit-proposal-bug/78617#78617) from Waffles explains the separation of the excerpt from the main wiki, but doesn't clarify which awards the badge.

Comment: Thanks for answering, however, @waffles [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94381/tag-editor-not-working/95728#95728) said something about the TagWikiExcerpt PostId, so I was under the impression I should have gotten it for that. Could anyone clarify this?

Comment: @takrl I hadn't seen that question before.  I have observed the behavior that I described when I got the badge.  I had edited the excerpt the week before and had not received the badge.

Comment: Thanks for adding the link to Waffles' answer, this one _I_ hadn't seen before.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63447/tag-editor-badge-description-incomplete/80164#80164

Comment: @Cody Thanks for finding that question.  The revised rules still don't seem to be true, though.

Comment: @Cody Thanks for this link, I had seen that post title, but didn't read it (silly me) as it seemed to concern only the tag description. But as my post suggests, it doesn't currently seem to work that way. Changing tags from support to bug ...

Comment: Since @Cody approved the excerpt edit and rejected the body edit I proposed for the _tag-editor-badge_ tag, we'll see later on if it works as expected now. It definetly didn't for last month's edit ...

Comment: Hrm, I guess I missed the fact you were trying to test the system. I didn't even tie the suggested edit back to you/this question. I didn't like codifying your current assessment into the tag wiki, though. I'm reasonably certain that I've gotten the tag badge for *either* edit, and Waffles's answer makes me even more certain of that.

Comment: @Cody My experience with it was on SO within the past couple of weeks.  This assumes the same code for the badge runs on both sites.  I had created an excerpt (which I suppose could be argued is not editing one), edited an excerpt, and finally edited the wiki proper before I got it.  This was over a few weeks, so it wasn't an issue of not waiting long enough for it.

Comment: @Cody That's fine, it would have really proven nothing if both edits got accepted and I had gotten the badge then. This way, we'll see if the excerpt edit is sufficient. So far, no sugar ... and I agree that the link to this question doesn't really fit in there. But in general, I think that within the tag wiki the rules for getting the badge could be explained, at least, if it's a difficult one like _Electorate_ for example.

Comment: @Cody Three days since you accepted the excerpt edit. I think we can safely call this a bug now ...

Comment: @takrl: Yeah, someone else has posted [the same bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101018/how-to-get-the-tag-editor-badge), albeit in reverse. Still waiting for an official response.

Comment: @Cody Actually, is exactly the same bug. I looked at it more closely today, and the example he gave was also an excerpt edit. I happened to edit the wiki body for _Newsletter_ here on meta today and got the badge within a few minutes. So it's definetly the excerpt edits that don't work for getting this badge.