# Tag Editor badge is not being awarded

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I have gotten the Tag Editor badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100877/should-i-have-gotten-the-tag-editor-badge)

I have edited a Tag Wiki but didn't get the badge (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5439208/revisions)). How come?

As far as I understand, it should be awarded after the first edit, is that correct?

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63447/tag-editor-badge-description-incomplete/80164#80164) indicates that you should receive the Tag Editor badge for *either* a tag wiki or a tag wiki excerpt edit, but that doesn't appear to be happening. [Someone else](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100877/should-i-have-gotten-the-tag-editor-badge) edited just the excerpt and didn't get the badge.

Comment: It looks like the tag is still not being awarded. I created many wiki tags in the past few days and got nothing.

Comment: Just wanted to post an update. I've edited two tags today and still got no badge. Is this a known bug, or am I missing something?