# Confusing review UI leads editors to accept tag wikis while rejecting corresponding excerpts

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, user-interface, tag-wiki

I suggested a few new tag wikis. Most were accepted, but in a few, the tag wiki body was accepted but the corresponding excerpt was rejected, leaving them with no summary.

I [inquired about it](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3043/tag-wikis-accepted-but-excerpts-rejected) on Super User meta. It turned out that they had been rejected accidentally by a user who had just gained review privileges (10k repuation). He said,

> I thought they were re-writes of previous edits.

More recently, it has [happened again](https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/4452), with a different editor (who had also just passed 10000 reputation).

I don't have access to the suggested edit review UI, but it seems that **the interface is confusing to users when reviewing suggestions for tag wiki excerpts**. Could it be changed to clear up the confusion?

#### Update

Something similar happened with someone's suggested edit pair with the edit summary "Moved the links from Excerpt to the description.": https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/314646 approved, https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/314797 rejected ("Why did you remove the linky?")

Comment: I agree, it's not very clear what you're looking at when you're reviewing an excerpt.

Comment: I agree about fixing this, any suggestions on what we can do to the UI?

Comment: @waffles, how about BIG, __bold__ and flashing :)

Comment: @waffles: how about just a slightly different background color for the tag wiki edits? (Like how the questions that have your favorite tags show up on the question pages with a different background shade.)

Comment: Actually, on Stack Overflow, sometimes I intentionally reject one of them while accepting the other one - simply since one of the edit proposals was quite bad.

Comment: Similar question/concern: [Tag wiki edit proposal bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78616/tag-wiki-edit-proposal-bug)

Comment: I don't have anything to add at the moment, but I'm grouping this with other things we're going to be looking at over the next few months.

Comment: I agree that there is possible confusion when reviewing tag-wiki edits made in conjunction with edits to their corresponding wiki-excerpts. However, neither of the two excerpt edits that you link include any **usage guidance**. On Stack Overflow, at least, there is a specific reason to reject excerpt edits for "Lacks usage guidance" and I am here assuming that the same is true on other sites (on none of which I have sufficient reputation to see the wiki-edit review UI).

Comment: ... also, you didn't include any usage guidance in any of the three edits you linked on the Super User site.

Comment: I've removed the tag here because this relates to a very old version of the UI, which has been updated several times since then. If you have concerns about this still, please ask a new question outlining the issues you're running into.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I propose the following changes to the UI to make it easier to tell when there is a related tag wiki excerpt and body proposal:

1. Group tag wiki excerpt suggestions with their related tag wiki suggestion
2. Change background color of grouped suggestions, and remove dotted line between them
3. Put the tag wiki excerpt suggestion before the tag wiki body suggestion
4. Change highlighted text to "added *n* characters in *excerpt*" instead of "in *body*"
5. Change "tag wiki" to "tag wiki body" (to compliment "tag wiki excerpt", which is already clarified
6. Highlight "body/excerpt" to indicate which type of edit it is
7. Provide a check box to apply the approve/deny action to both the tag wiki body and the tag wiki excerpt at the same time. This makes life easier, and visually reinforces that they are related.

[image]

Comment: That looks great to me. Not sure the checkbox is all that useful though.