# Please show suggested edits to tag wikis and the corresponding excerpt together

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review, tag-wiki

When there are many suggested edits in the queue, a random selection of them is shown.

This is more annoying than useful, but there's a case when it's especially annoying: if someone edits both a tag wiki and the corresponding excerpt, the two are not shown together to reviewers. This leads to extra reviewing effort.

Please ensure that suggested edits to a tag wiki and the corresponding excerpt are always shown together. (Keep allowing different decisions, of course.)

I guess this feature request won't be implemented until the new [community tasks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137174/new-feature-community-review-tasks) UI comes out, but please do make sure it's done there.

Comment: Related: [Confusing review UI leads editors to accept tag wikis while rejecting corresponding excerpts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103380/confusing-review-ui-leads-editors-to-accept-tag-wikis-while-rejecting-correspond)