# Consolidate tag wiki excerpt and body contents with regards to suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

At the moment, in major part because they are two separate post objects in the system, the excerpt and the body of a tag wiki count as two separate posts with regards to suggested edits in the queue. Mechanically, this is sane, but when it comes to handling the actual queue, it can be confusing. A body edit might consist of little more than a bed of links, which looks bad. But then an excerpt is shown that includes the rest of the data, and since excerpts can be included on the actual wiki page, it makes a lot more sense when they're taken in the same space.

And this is how they are composed, too. The actual edit interface for working on tag wikis has both the excerpt and the body on the same page. In a sense, the excerpt behaves a lot like the "title" of the wiki, if we make a parallel to normal post edits.

Thus, my suggestion (which is to say a suggestion that I repossessed from Robert Cartaino) is that when suggested edits are reviewed for tag wikis, that they be presented in a single unit, treating the excerpt the same as how a title is treated in a question edit. This way, relevant information that is crossed between the two isn't lost because they are reviewed separately.

Comment: Isn't this bad for cases where only the excerpt sucks? That's not to say that the current implementation doesn't complicate things, though.

Comment: It's an [old request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137620/please-show-suggested-edits-to-tag-wikis-and-the-corresponding-excerpt-together) that I don't remember borrowing from Robert. I'm voting to close mine because it's worded in terms of the old review queue. The concern remains the same.

Comment: After reviewing a lot of tag edits today I second this request. Has there been any official answer to why this is not / will not be implemented.

Comment: I got tricked yesterday by the UI. [Why can't I submit this meta tag wiki edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379825/352329)