# Why can't I submit this meta tag wiki edit?

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, per-site-meta, tag-wiki-excerpt

I am reviewing some tag edit suggestions on Meta Joomla Stack Exchange from [a user looking to fix a broad-reaching problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379090/352329). The suggested edit by the user wasn't as full as what is on Stack Overflow, so I decided to *Improve Edit* (so that they get points for helping) and copy-paste the full text from Stack Overflow.

However, it doesn't let me.  There is a generic validation error, but no actual error message.

> Your edit couldn't be submitted. Please see the error above.

What gives?  I also, tried Reject and Edit, but that failed in the same manner.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for approving the edit - I understand that the problem I described in the linked post is rather unimportant. (It is quite plausible that almost nobody will see the tag-info for that tag.) So I hope that my edit suggestions didn't cause too much trouble.

Comment: Does an accepted tag wiki edit come with a reputation points award on a *meta* site (Meta Joomla Stack Exchange)? - except this very site.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Um, no.  Duh. I don't know why I was thinking that either.   `!!coffee`. I suppose wanting to appreciate their contribution gets them closer to the Research Assistant badge.

Answer (score 13):

Removing the paragraph with the `[meta-tag:status-planned]` text did the trick.  I was able to submit the edit from the review queue.

Ah, I see my mistake now.  I thought I was editing the "tag wiki", but I was editing the "tag excerpt" -- which does not allow Markdown formatting.  (I'll fix my bad edit now.)

However, I still think the UX should be improved.