# Why are tag wiki edits from low-rep users split into two requests?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

Some time ago, I suggested an edit to the [cypress tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cypress) on Stack Overflow, as it was poorly worded and lacking in my view. I made the changes I saw fit, and submitted my suggestion.

To my surprise, my edit was split into two requests. [One was approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20469885), but [the other was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20469884). I stand by both edits, but I can understand why a reviewer might reject the second; I believe it improved the flow, and it fixed an awkward run-on, but I would not have submitted it alone and I can see why it may have seemed superfluous.

To this day, it stands as [my only rejected edit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8166701/joshua-wade?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

I intended the edits to be proposed together, and that's what I thought would happen. I was following the guidance to [make edits as complete as possible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303220/8166701), and there was no indication that this was *two* edits, not just one:

> Your edit *(singular)* will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.

Here is what the tag edit page looks like for low-rep users:

> [image: Screenshot of tag wiki edit page (1)]

And below the edit preview, here's the change description and submit button:

> [image: Screenshot of tag wiki edit page (2)]

I may have missed it, but I see no indication that excerpt and wiki edits will be separated.

I'd like to request one of two things:

1. Bundle tag wiki edits as one edit request, or
2. Use explicit language to indicate that edits will be split.

Comment: The *why* is simple; because you're editing two posts, not one. The button does say "Save Edit**s**" (but it does so for Q&A edits as well).

Comment: Is there anywhere the wiki is shown without the excerpt? If no, then it shouldn’t be shown to reviewers in isolation. (I seem to recall ranting about the same thing with suggested edits to answers: it’s hard to tell the difference between a question and answer and sometimes you’d want the context of the question to do the review.)

Comment: Joshua, the tag, excerpt, and Wiki are three things; and on some sites it's tough to get decent excerpts (which can be submitted without the wiki) let alone a well thought out wiki. It's a large (if you do it all) important edit - netting a new (low rep) user **4** rep. --- Are you suggesting awarding half the reputation for however much is done (if it survives review) leaving the remainder for no reward, or you must do it all for half reputation, or increase the rep., or ...

Comment: Related: [Tag wiki edit proposal bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78616/289905).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Consolidate tag wiki excerpt and body contents with regards to suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182415/consolidate-tag-wiki-excerpt-and-body-contents-with-regards-to-suggested-edits) (and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137620)